# more than one field has the search text in solr

Tags: solr

I have below four default fields based on the selection among only cvs, feedbacks and records or a combination or all of them :
cv_text
cv_feedbacks
cv_records
cv_records_feedbacks

All four fields are text_general type which is defined as

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When I try to search for special words like C++ or C#, then solr is returning search results only if default search field is cv_records even though there are C++ or C# words in other fields as well.

Comment: What does your query string look like? You can use `qf` to provide the fields to query.

Comment: "q": "cv_text:(C++)" is the query
 
  I will select the default field based on the radio buttons selected from the front end UI.

the radio buttons are
1. records
2. feedbacks

Answer (score 0):

This is because

a) you're using the (default) lucene query parser without explicitly mention target fields (i.e. your query contains only terms). In this case the default field is used

b) you're using an (e)dismax query parser and your qf param contains only that field

After seeing your comment I guess you're on the first option. So I suggest you to

- check the solr logs to see that your gui is sending the right query
- repeat the same query in a browser and add debug=true. You will see how Solr "sees" the query
- use the schema browser in the Solr admin and check the content of the fields that don't return results...maybe they are empty (i.e. you're indexed nothing in those fields)

Comment: can you please elaborate @Andrea